# Did Rabbi Yehudah ben Bateira not come for the Regel?

Tags: rabbis, maseches-pesachim, korban-pesach, shalosh-regalim

The gemara in [Pesachim 3b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pesachim.3b.10-12?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en) brings a story in which Rabbi Yehudah ben Bateira discovers that an Aramean non-Jew is eating from the Korban Pesach in Yerushalayim. He tricks him into outing him to the authorities in Yerushalayim. The story concludes with the authorities contacting Rabbi Yehudah and telling him:

> "They sent a message to Rabbi Yehuda ben Bateira: Peace unto you, Rabbi Yehuda ben Beteira, as you are in Netzivin and your net is spread in Jerusalem. Despite your distance from Jerusalem, you enabled us to apprehend a person who deceived us."

Does this mean that Rabbi Yehudah ben Bateira himself didn't come (for at least two consecutive years, according to the story) to Yerushalayim during the Regel (being that he had to trick the Aramean instead of outing him to the proper authorities himself)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Tosfos](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Pesachim.3b.11.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) there explains

> ורבי יהודה בן בתירא שלא עלה לרגל י"ל שלא היה לו קרקע או זקן היה שאינו יכול להלך ברגליו דפטור מפסח כמו מראיה א"נ נציבין חו"ל היא כדמוכח בסיפרי בפ' ראה ועוד בתרגום ירושלמי (בראשית י) וארך ואכד וכלנה בארץ שנער מתרגם והדס ונציבין וקטיספי

He says he either did not have land, or he was old, or he was in Chutz Laaretz.

Comment: Thanks. I can understand the old part, but I don't really understand the other explanations: a. What does not having land have to do with Korban Pesach? b. I take the author of this Tosfot didn't have the Yalkut Shimoni (compiled in the time of Rashi) where [it explicitly says](https://www.sefaria.org.il/search?q=%D7%A9%D7%94%D7%99%D7%95%20%D7%94%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9F&tab=text&tvar=1&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance) that Netzivin is not in Eretz Yisrael, and in fact, that was my hava amina; that was where my question stemmed from.

Comment: The Yaavetz and many others ask that question on Tosfos, not having land is a patur from Regel but not Pesach. The Cheshek Shlomo answers. The Maharsham has a list of places to look. https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37955&st=&pgnum=470